# Ternary Operator Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ternary

I have `$scope.lineData[0].line` in my controller. I want to check `$scope.lineData[0] != undefined` , If so then `$scope.lineData[0].line` else just `"0"` value to add. How can do this with angular JS ?

Can anyone help me to do this?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: `var x = $scope.lineData[0] !== undefined ? $scope.lineData[0].line : 0;`

Comment: @Satpal : Thank you.. Its working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Template we would do it something like

```
{{ lineData[0] ? lineData[0].line : "0" }}
```

In Controller, we'll be doing

```
var some_value = $scope.lineData[0] ? $scope.lineData[0].line : "0";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

`{{ $scope.lineData[0] ? $scope.lineData[0].line : "0" }}`

**Update**

You could also simply do:

`{{ $scope.lineData[0].line || "0" }}`

Angular will coalesce from left to right, the first non-null/undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it according to your usecase, Few of those might be :

1) ex. `<input ng-value="getLine()" />`

2) ex. `<div>{{lineData[0] ? lineData[0].line : "0"}}</div>`

3) ex. in Controller, `var value = $scope.lineData[0] ? $scope.lineData[0].line : "0";`

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-value="getLine()" />
    <div>{{lineData[0] ? lineData[0].line : "0"}}</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.lineData = [{
        line : 3,
    }];

    $scope.getLine = function() {
        return $scope.lineData[0] ? $scope.lineData[0].line : "0";
    }

}
```

**JSFiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/v6ezygy2/